# How do I fit a non-rectangular grid to a sample of x and y coordinates?

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation

I would like to make a lookup table for un-warping a given image projected onto the interior of a dome. The apparatus looks something like [this](http://paulbourke.net/dome/iDome/), but smaller (for a mouse). I have collected a set of points which define a low-resolution grid of evenly spaced points on the interior of the dome.

Here are the coordinates:

[(744, 498),
(721, 526),
(686, 541),
(649, 543),
(598, 537),
(561, 519),
(546, 495),
(479, 541),
(436, 600),
(442, 654),
(500, 682),
(577, 701),
(639, 708),
(694, 707),
(786, 684),
(844, 659),
(854, 596),
(813, 538),
(520, 566),
(485, 627),
(582, 589),
(569, 652),
(644, 593),
(643, 659),
(702, 591),
(711, 653),
(750, 569),
(774, 633)]

Here's what the grid looks like:

[image]

I'd like to create a grid that is the same size as the actual display (720 x 1280) fit to the coordinates that I have collected. Is there a way to "fit" a non-rectangular grid to a set of points like this, and if so how could this approach be implemented with Python?

Edit:

Thanks to @bogovicj, I was able to solve this problem (I think). The solution is below.

```
# image transformation
from skimage import transform as tf
src = <x and y coordinates from source grid>
dst = <x and y coordinates from the destination grid>
tform =tf.estimate_transform(ttype='piecewise-affine', src=src, dst=dst)
base_image = <some image of the shape 720 rows by 1280 columns>
warped_image = tf.warp(base_image, inverse_map=tform.inverse)

# plot the results
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax1.imshow(base_image, cmap='gray')
ax1.scatter(src[:,0], src[:,1], color='r', marker='+', s=100)
ax2.imshow(warped_image, cmap='gray')
ax2.scatter(dst[:,0], dst[:,1], color='r', marker='+', s=100)
```

[image]

It seems like the transform estimation had a little trouble handling the concavity of the top of the destination grid, but other than that it looks great and will probably improve with a higher resolution source/destination grid.

Comment: @ your problem seems to be **"How to solve radial distortion Problem"**, a practical solution can be found [here](https://github.com/xiaoyu258/GeoProj) using Deep Learning.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to map the boundary of your region to the boundary of your rectangular image? And that the four "arcs" of seven points each should map to parallel, horizontal lines?  This may help: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.estimate_transform

Comment: @bogovicj, yea this is exactly what I want to do (sorry the question wasn't clear on this). this looks promising. This approach looks very promising. I'm going to try it out tomorrow and if it works I'll edit my post to include the solution.

Comment: Great!  Yea, I was hoping piecewise affine would behave better. Scipy has some more options for interpolation that scikit image doesn't have, maybe try those? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html Maybe cubic- or thin-plate-splines would work better?